# Speed up Telegram Bot API in PHP

Tags: php, curl, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I have used PHP in order to write a Telegram bot that uses `webhook` which means that the PHP file is called for each update. I have used curl in order to post JSON to https://api.telegram.org. When I send a message in my PHP file, it responds in around **1 second**. I think because it does not reuse the curl connection. the connection closes after the PHP file finishes.

I have also written a Java application that calls `getUpdate` method every 5 seconds. It responds in around **500 milliseconds** because it reuses the connection.

How can I speed up my PHP bot just like my Java application? Is there any way to reuse the connection even when the PHP file is finished and another PHP file is run?

Here is my PHP code:

```
function Post($method, $data)
{
    $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$authenticationToken."/".$method;
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING,  '');
    $resultJSON = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $result = json_decode($resultJSON,true);
    if(!$result["ok"])
        LogF($resultJSON);
    return $result;
}
```

P.S: the ping time of the URL is around **200 milliseconds**.

Comment: Without seing the code it's impossible to say something about that code, don't you think?

Comment: @fvu alright I will add my PHP code

Comment: @MatinLotfaliee Your code is in `webhook` kind. In this kind of dealeing, your code is logically one time processable, not two times or more(eg, 5 times!)

Comment: PHP can't save open connection for cURL, you can use another language to speed up network processing. Take a look at Node.js